# Python C API: What does PyList_Append do on error?

Tags: python, cpython, python-c-api

This is not documented in the docs. It just says it "returns 0 for success and -1 for error". What does this mean?

If we're iterating over some data structure (say a linked list/array) and we're adding elements as we iterate, and suddenly `PyList_Append` returns `-1` - what happens? Does the elements that **did** get added, have their reference count decremented or does Python just die and de-allocating / decrementing reference counts is the least of my worries?

If the elements that thus far *was* added have their reference count decremented then I understand nothing has to be done, as in this case, my de-allocation function handles decrementing of other reference counts where it needs to (if the element's reference count reaches 0) - but if Python just throws it's hands up and say "you're on your own" - I would have to make sure I manage the reference counting at time of error, immediately (or suffer a reference leak).

So which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are two errors that can occur with `PyList_Append`:

- `MemoryError` (if it had to enlarge the allocated memory for the list, and was unable to allocate enough).
- `SystemError` if you pass it something that isn't a list. You should be able to avoid this through appropriate type-checks so if your code is written correctly it should never happen.

In both cases:

- The existing contents of the list are still part of the list (and their reference count doesn't change). These are owned by the list and their reference count will be reduced by 1 when the list is destroyed, therefore you don't need to do anything special with them,
- The element you were trying to add is not added, and its reference count remains unchanged. You as the caller own 1 reference to it (in both the success and failure cases) that you probably want to `DECREF`.

Practically memory-errors are hard to recover from - most operating systems over-allocate memory so by the time you actually see a memory error you've usually run out a while ago.

---

Example (untested) code showing roughly what you'd do:

```c
PyObject *make_list(int n) {
    PyObject* list = PyList_New(0);
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        PyObject *toAdd = PyLong_FromLong(i);
        if (!toAdd) goto bad;
        int appendRes = PyList_Append(list, toAdd);
        Py_DECREF(toAdd);  // decref this whatever the result of append
        if (appendRes < 0) goto bad;
    }
    if (0) {
        bad:
        Py_CLEAR(list);  // decref and set list to NULL - this will clean up any of list contents that were already
    }
    return list;
}
```